# A value of type 'CatalogModel?' cant be assigned to variable type 'CatalogModel'

Tags: flutter, dart, velocity

I created a class and tried assigning a variable to it which resulted in the following error.

```
class MyStore extends VxStore{
  CatalogModel? catalog;
  CartModel? cart;

  MyStore() {
    catalog = CatalogModel(); 
    cart!.catalog = catalog; //error
    cart = CartModel();
  }
}
```

I tried using null check but it did not help.

Comment: Use `cart!.catalog = catalog!;`. Also move `cart= CartModel();` above that line, otherwise the cart is null and you can't access `cart!.catalog`

Comment: Yeah thanks it worked !! How did adding a null check after catalog typecasted the previous variable type to 'CatalogModel?' ?

Comment: After referring a CatalogModel, the type is still CarModel?, but initialized.

Answer (score 0):

When the Cart contains the Catalog, why does it need both? Anyways i hope i understood the goal a created a working solution. I hope it fits:

If you want to build set the CatalogModel and CartModel in the constructor, why should it be nullable? You could build it like this:

```
class MyStore extends VxStore{
  CatalogModel? catalog;
  CartModel? cart;
      
  MyStore({this.cart, this.catalog});
          
}

class CatalogModel{

}

class CartModel{
    CartModel({required this.catalog});
  final CatalogModel catalog;
}

class VxStore{}

final CartModel cart = CartModel(catalog: CatalogModel());

final myStore = MyStore(cart: cart, catalog: cart.catalog);
```

Note: the {}-braces in the constructor are for named-Constructors. If you are unfamilar with that, look here: [Dart - Constructors](https://dart.dev/language/constructors)